# How can I remove an input method completely in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, input-languages

I have upgraded to Windows 8 Pro from Windows 7 Home Premium. Recently, I noticed that there's 2 input language methods in my computer (English and Vietnamese):

[image: 1]

But I don't want to use that built-in Vietnamese input method of Microsoft, I want to remove it, so I went to Language page, but what I saw is there's no Vietnamese entry there?

[image: 2]

I tried myself for a while, then I found the solution:

- Add Vietnamese input method
- Remove it again

Then I got this (Keyboard button is disabled):

[image: 3]

I would like to set my computer like that, but after restarting my computer, it gets back like the first picture again, I don't know why, it should be like I set it before I restart my computer.

Anyone can explain or give a solution to remove the Vietnamese entry?

Comment: If you click the Options link for English (US), what does it say? See if any Vietnamese input methods are perhaps added.

Comment: Did you mean the first picture? If you meant so, then it says nothing, nothing change if I choose Vietnamese or English, still US Keyboard input method. And yes, I added Vietnamese input method once, and even installed Vietnamese language pack, and I removed it already, but the Vietnamese input method still remains?

Comment: anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Open Regedit, find and delete this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\0000042a

100% successful!

Comment: **Warning**: The instructions contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Comment: @Ramhound If I understand correctly. This will completely remove the language input from the system (Vietnamese in this case), therefore it will unable to be displayed again. But you also unable to add this input later since it was removed form the registry.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I see that. Just want to add some words in case someone found this answer.

Comment: @sonnb - You didn't have to ping me to do that....